# vscode and plantuml 2.11.1 fails to include files specified by environmental variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables, plantuml

Using vscode for plantuml, the latest PlantUML extension version, 2.11.1, seems to break generation of diagrams specifically when including files with environment variables.
And it works when we downgrade the extension version to 2.11.0.

Example plantuml code:

```
@startuml
!include %HOME%/plantuml_macros/stdmacros.txt

title ABCDXXXX
---
```

Error in preview diagram is:[image]

How can I use environmental variables in include path in plantuml 2.11.1 ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a wild guess, did you try `$HOME` instead of `%HOME%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preprocessor has been changed in last version (see http://plantuml.com/preprocessing )

Could you try this way :

```
!include %getenv("HOME")/plantuml_macros/stdmacros.txt
```

And tell us if it's working this way. Thanks

Comment: You also have to use a newer version of plantuml. At first i tried to do it with version 1.2017.15 (latest on Ubuntu 18.04) and it didn't work for me. latest version can be downloaded: https://plantuml.com/download